# Scaling t-SNE to millions of observations in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

t-SNE can supposedly scale to millions of observations (see [here](https://lvdmaaten.github.io/tsne/)), but I'm curious how that can be true, at least in the Sklearn implementation.

I'm trying it on a dataset with ~100k items, each with ~190 features. Now, I'm aware that I can do a first pass of dimensionality reduction with, e.g. PCA, but the problem seems more fundamental.

t-SNE computes and stores the full, dense similarity matrix calculated for the input observations (
I've confirmed this by looking at the [source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/51a765a/sklearn/manifold/t_sne.py#L496)). In my case, this is a 10 *billion* element dense matrix, which by itself requires 80 GB+ of memory. Extrapolate this to just one million observations, and you're looking at 8 *terabytes* of RAM just to store the distance matrix (let alone computation time...)

So, how can we possibly scale t-SNE to millions of datapoints in the sklearn implementation? Am I missing something? The [sklearn docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.TSNE.html) at least imply that it's possible:

> By default the gradient calculation algorithm uses Barnes-Hut approximation running in O(NlogN) time. method=’exact’ will run on the slower, but exact, algorithm in O(N^2) time. The exact algorithm should be used when nearest-neighbor errors need to be better than 3%. *However, the exact method cannot scale to millions of examples.*

That's my emphasis, but I would certainly read that as implying the Barnes-hut method *can* scale to millions of examples, but I'll reiterate that the code requires calculating the full distance matrix well before we even get to any of the actual t-sne transformations (with or without Barnes-hut).

So am I missing something? Is it possible to scale this up to millions of datapoints?

Comment: related: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/4619

Comment: Interesting. Thing is, I've tried the c++ implementation mentioned in that thread (see last comment there), and it seems to work fine with 100k items. What's weird is that skimming through the [code](https://github.com/lvdmaaten/bhtsne/blob/master/tsne.cpp) suggests that it should have the same issue, in that it still calculates the full distance matrix. Or at least I think it is...I don't know c++ very well at all.

Comment: I've confirmed that the c++ method does scale nicely, but I'm not totally sure how/why. Plus it's limited to operating on euclidean distances. If I could find a version that scaled as well but could work with other distance metrics, I'd be really happy...

Answer (score 2):

Barnes-Hut does NOT require you to compute and storex the full, dense similarity matrix calculated for the input observations.

Also, take a look at the references mentioned at the documentation. In particular, [this one](https://lvdmaaten.github.io/tsne/). Quoting that page:

> The technique can be implemented via Barnes-Hut approximations, allowing it to be applied on large real-world datasets. We applied it on data sets with up to 30 million examples.

That page also links to this talk about how the approximation works: [Visualizing Data Using t-SNE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RJVL80Gg3lA&list=UUtXKDgv1AVoG88PLl8nGXmw).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you using another algorithm called **UMAP**. It is proven to perform at least as well as t-SNE and in most cases, it performs better. Most importantly, it scales significantly better. Their approach to the problem is similar so they generate similar results but UMAP is a lot faster (Look at the last graph here: https://umap-learn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/benchmarking.html). You can look at the original paper and the following link for details.

https://www.nature.com/articles/nbt.4314.pdf

[https://towardsdatascience.com/how-exactly-umap-works-13e3040e1668#:~:text=tSNE%20is%20Dead.&text=Despite%20tSNE%20made%20a%20dramatic,be%20fixed%20sooner%20or%20later](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-exactly-umap-works-13e3040e1668#:%7E:text=tSNE%20is%20Dead.&text=Despite%20tSNE%20made%20a%20dramatic,be%20fixed%20sooner%20or%20later).

Answer (score 0):

OpenVisuMap (at github) implements t-SNE without resorting to approximation. It uses GPU to calculate the distance matrix on-fly. It still has O(N^2) calculation complexity, but only O(N) memory complexity.